# Can't get calendar to appear on click - no JS errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker

When I click on the text box or icon, I can't get the popup calendar to appear. I get no JavaScript errors and just can't seem to work out what the issue is.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
  $('#datetimepicker input').click(function(event) {
     $('#datetimepicker').data("DateTimePicker").show(); 
  });
</script>

<!-- in the body -->
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" id="datetimepicker" class="form-control" name="date">
  <label class="input-group-addon btn" for="date">
    <span class="fa fa-calendar open-datetimepicker"></span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong as I'm really confused now and can't seem to work it out.

Thanks

Comment: try using css, display: none and display: block on click, instead of show() hide()

Comment: The datetimepicker control is not a standard part of jQuery, and you haven't referenced any other libraries. Are you sure that you're looking at the right place for errors, as if that was the source of your problem there would definitely be one.

Comment: I would recommend you to use standard HTML elements whenever possible. Nowadays <input type="date"> is supported for all modern browsers.

Answer (score 0):

In document.ready you have to initialize the datepicker just use this

```
$("#datetimepicker ").datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'd-M-yy'
});
```

and it will automatically show calendar when you click on input type

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you've correctly imported jQuery, jQuery DateTimePicker JS & CSS. Then use `datetimepicker` simply as following, **no need of a *click* event** -

```js
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.min.css" />

<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" id="datetimepicker" class="form-control" name="date">
    <label class="input-group-addon btn" for="date">
       <span class="fa fa-calendar open-datetimepicker"></span>
    </label>
</div>
```